# How to get only valid htmlContent using java?

Tags: java, html, validation

I am looking for help on:

How I can get only valid HTML from a given "htmlContent" as String object?

Example....my htmlContent looks like....

```
<p>   some.   
         <b> some text</b>  
         text
</p>

</span>
</strong>
</p>
```

As you can see I have the last three   orphan html tags which must go away and return value would only looks like:

```
<p>   some.   
         <b> some text</b>  
         text
</p>
```

Is there a way I get my expected result as stated above?

*I am dealing with huge sized and so many html docs that has such issues and I need to clean this up.*

**Your help is greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Use [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/howto.html) or the JTidyServlet.

Comment: What you have tried so far, please post some code.

Comment: You can use a Stack to check whether the HTML tags are balanced.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187539/java-balanced-expressions-check