# Wrong values when matching strings of html tags

Tags: java, logic

I've been working on something that checks if an HTML file is well-formed (No self-closing tags for simplicity). I filtered everything but the text of the tag and the "/" if it has one using splits. Ex: p, /p

I'm getting a value of true for things such as "head, title, /head, /title", but it is passing all of my other test cases..

My logic for seeing if these are well-formed is to dequeue the tags, if it does not contain "/" push into a stack, if it does I check to see if the value from my queue matches the pop value from my stack etc.

I feel like I'm making some kind of basic logical error that I'm just not seeing after staring at it for so long.

```
while (!tags.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            temp = tags.dequeue();
            if (!temp.contains("/")) {
                openTags.push(temp);
                counter++;
            }
            if (temp.contains("/")) {
                String open = openTags.pop();
                split = temp.split("/");
                temp = split[1];
                if (counter == 0) { //check if first item contained "/" (automatically invalid)
                    return false;
                }
                if (!temp.equalsIgnoreCase(open)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } catch (EmptyCollectionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TagValidation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question can help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187539/java-balanced-expressions-check.

Comment: @CodeFishBoy I may have just fixed it. I think I was doing something stupid elsewhere. I'll definitely look that over either way because it's more to learn :)