# Mismatch results for the same input on leetCode

Tags: java

For the problem 20. Valid Parentheses on leetCode, I wrote the following code. https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/

It asks if the three types of brackets close in order and all matches in pair.

Since this question was in my complexity course, so I wrote a solution that could be done within logrithm space, which is completely unnecessary for solving this problem... This is not my point tho.

The problem I faced to is that I tried to run it on my own local app, for the input "()[]{}" I got a true, but it was a false in the test on leetCode. It feels really weird to me.

If you run my code with the input "()[]{}", what do you get?
What caused this problem?

```
class Solution18_1 {
    private Map<Character, Character> otherSide = new HashMap<>();
    private int t1l = -1, t2l = -1, t3l = -1, t1r = Integer.MAX_VALUE, t2r = Integer.MAX_VALUE, t3r = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    private void initializeMap() {
        otherSide.put('{', '}');
        otherSide.put('(', ')');
        otherSide.put('[', ']');
    }

    public boolean isValid(String s) {
        initializeMap();
        //step one, check if all three types match on numbers,
        // a { must have a }, so for the other two types
        int matchCounter = 0;
        matchCounter = matchCheck('{', s);
        if (matchCounter != 0) return false;
        matchCounter = matchCheck('[', s);
        if (matchCounter != 0) return false;
        matchCounter = matchCheck('(', s);
        if (matchCounter != 0) return false;

        //step two, check if order matches
        //When we firstly read a type, we start to find the indices of this pair
        //if the next read type is the same as the last one, we update the pointers.
        //if the next read type is not the same type, we find the pair and compare the orders
        char lastType = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
//            System.out.println("dealing with index " + i + ",the current char is " + s.charAt(i) + ", and matchCount = " + matchCounter
//                    + ", last type is " + lastType);
            if (lastType == 0) {
                lastType = s.charAt(i);
                matchCounter = 1;
                if (lastType == '{') t1l = i;
                if (lastType == '[') t2l = i;
                if (lastType == '(') t3l = i;
            } else if (matchCounter != 0 && s.charAt(i) == lastType) {
                matchCounter++;
            } else if (matchCounter != 0 && s.charAt(i) == otherSide.get(lastType)) {
                matchCounter--;
                if (matchCounter == 0) {
                    //pairs located, check if matches
                    //and go back to the corresponding index
//                    System.out.print("Going back, ");
                    if (lastType == '{') {
//                        System.out.println("we read {, hence use t1l : " + t1l);
                        t1r = i;
                        i = t1l;
                        if (!checkMatch(1)) return false;
                    }
                    if (lastType == '[') {
//                        System.out.println("we read [, hence use t2l : " + t2l);
                        t2r = i;
                        i = t2l;
                        if (!checkMatch(2)) return false;
                    }
                    if (lastType == '(') {
//                        System.out.println("we read (, hence use t3l : " + t3l);
                        t3r = i;
                        i = t3l;
                        if (!checkMatch(3)) return false;
                    }
                }
            } else if (matchCounter == 0 && s.charAt(i) == lastType) {
                matchCounter = 1;
                if (lastType == '{') t1l = i;
                if (lastType == '[') t2l = i;
                if (lastType == '(') t3l = i;
            } else if (matchCounter == 0 && (s.charAt(i) != lastType && s.charAt(i) != otherSide.get(lastType))) {
//                System.out.println("\nChanging lastType by " + s.charAt(i));
                matchCounter = 1;
                lastType = s.charAt(i);
                if (lastType == '{') t1l = i;
                if (lastType == '[') t2l = i;
                if (lastType == '(') t3l = i;
            }


        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean checkMatch(int i) {
        if (i == 1) {
            if (t1l < t2l && t1r > t2r) {
                if (t1r < t2r) return false;
            } else if (t1l > t2l && t1l < t2r) {
                if (t1r > t2r) return false;
            }

            if (t1l < t3l && t1r > t3r) {
                if (t1r < t3r) return false;
            } else if (t1l > t3l && t1l < t3r) {
                if (t1r > t3r) return false;
            }
        } else if (i == 2) {
            if (t2l < t1l && t2r > t1r) {
                if (t2r < t1r) return false;
            } else if (t2l > t1l && t2l < t1r) {
                if (t2r > t1r) return false;
            }

            if (t2l < t3l && t2r > t3r) {
                if (t2r < t3r) return false;
            } else if (t2l > t3l && t2l < t1r) {
                if (t2r > t3r) return false;
            }

        } else if (i == 3) {
            if (t3l < t1l && t3r > t1r) {
                if (t3r < t1r) return false;
            } else if (t3l > t1l && t3l < t1r) {
                if (t3r > t1r) return false;
            }

            if (t3l < t2l && t3r > t2r) {
                if (t3r < t2r) return false;
            } else if (t3l > t2l && t3l < t2r) {
                if (t3r > t2r) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private int matchCheck(char key, String s) {
        int matchCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == key) {
                matchCounter++;
            } else if (s.charAt(i) == otherSide.get(key)) {
                matchCounter--;
                if (matchCounter < 0) return -1;
            }
        }
        return matchCounter;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Generally, less code means less places for bugs to hide. How about `return s.replace("()","").replace("[]","").replace("{}","").isEmpty();` instead? Or a little fancier, `return s.matches("(\\(\\)|\\[]|\\{})*");`. This problem is well within one line territory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java balanced expressions check {\[()\]}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187539/java-balanced-expressions-check)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, this problem is stating that for the parentheses pair to be valid, it must meet one of two possible conditions.

1. It is immediately followed by a matching, closing bracket.
2. Or, it is immediately followed by an opening bracket.

So, for example `()[]` is valid.  Same with `{[]()}` and `[[]]`.
Something along the lines of `}[`, or `[{])`, is considered invalid.

Your code, for this task, is incredibly complex.

Try the "Discussions" tab, on leetcode.  There are quite a few, basic Java implementations.

Comment: My problem is just the results mismatch. I ran the same input on my own app the result was true. But I got a false when I ran it on leetCode with the exact same implementation. I just don't know what caused this, and I'd like to see if others run my code would the result be true or false. If others get true, it means my code works.

Comment: Since I had this problem in one of my complexity courses, and it required me to solve it within log space. Hence I had this solution in my mind. I was wondering how could such a complicated problem be an "easy", haha

Comment: @GabeEbag, I understand now; I missed the logic part.  I will run the code and update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

"()[]{}" is a very simple input because it has no nesting of parentheses. To solve things like "([{()}])" for instance, you will need some kind of stack.

Your code is much too complicated anyway.

Comment: Yeah, a stack would perfectly solve it, thank you. But would you please have a look at my code? If you think it is safe could you give it a run? I got true when I run it locally, but on leetCode it outputs a false.

Comment: I have tested it with "()[]{}", it returns `false` indeed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then there must be something wrong with my code. a little bit frustrating